# Java Rest Client bodyToMono generic

Tags: java, generics, spring-webflux, webclient

My application have some services to different rest endpoints. The Logic is always the same, so I wanted to use inheritance and generics to avoid code duplication. But one line (`bodyToMono(E[].class)`) does not work. Is there an alternative (maybe best practice way) to go, I don't see?

Parent Class:

```
@Configuration
@Service
public abstract class AbstractEntitiesRestService<E>{

   protected abstract String getBaseUrl();

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("webClient")
   protected WebClient WebClient;

    @Override
    public E[] getObjectsFromCustomQueryImpl(CustomQuery query) {
        return jtWebClient.get()
                .uri(getBaseUrl())
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(E[].class) <---- Error!
                .block();
    }
}
```

Child Class:

```
@Configuration
@Service
public class UserService extends AbstractEntitiesRestService<User> {

    @Value("${endpoint}")
    protected String baseUrl;

    @Override
    protected  String getBaseUrl(){
        return baseUrl;
    }
    
    ...

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

an array `[]` is not a type, so it can't be generalized.

so `T[].class` is an error since an array is not a `class`.

You need to use a class that holds types, since types can be generic. For instance an `ArrayList`.

```
@Override
public List<T> getObjectsFromCustomQueryImpl(CustomQuery query) {
    return jtWebClient.get()
            .uri(getBaseUrl())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>>() {})
            .block();
}
```

`ArrayList` is an implementation of the `List<T>` interface. But we cant place an interface containing a generic, `List<T>.class` wont work either so spring has a specific class `ParameterizedTypeReference` that is a class that will hold the type information for you, during de/serialization.

Comment: ParameterizedTypeReference did the trick! Already found some example solutions with that but it did not work .. obviously because I used the array .. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: ParameterizedTypeReference is better that doing Template.class